# How to delete an Xcode Server integration in Server 5.0.15

Tags: xcode, osx-server, xcode-server

I am currently running OS X Server 5.0.15 and I am trying to delete an Xcode Server Integration, but it doesn't looks like there are a obvious way to do that.

[image: The Server Screen]

[image: The Detail Screen]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode Server integrations are managed from Xcode itself. Open the Report Navigator in the left hand pane of Xcode. Locate the Bot integration you want to delete, right-click/control-click the integration and select "Delete Integration".

[image: Xcode Bot Integrations]